# Hamiltonian with ladder operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum

I have this Hamiltonian:

$$H=\frac{L_- L_+}{2I} + \frac{L_z^2}{2I_z}$$

with $I$ the moment of inertia and $\ell=1$.
I need to determine the eigen-states with the application of the ladder operators on the states.

I know how to apply $L|\ell,m\rangle $, $L_z|\ell,m\rangle$, $L_-|\ell,m\rangle$ and $L_+|\ell,m\rangle$.

I got stuck because it asks for using $L_-|\ell,m\rangle$ and $L_+|\ell,m\rangle$ and I don't how to use them together.

Comment: The eigenstates and other properties of the angular momentum operators are discussed in any good quantum mechanics textbooks. I suggest that you consult a few of them and pose a more precise question, if you encounter any difficulties.

Comment: I'm having a hard time tbh

Comment: I understand. But you have at least to try and indicate in your question where you are getting stuck. Otherwise it gives impression that you have made no effort.

Comment: First you apply $L_+$ on the state, get a new state, then you apply $L_-$ on the new state and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have that
$$
L_{+}L_{-}=\frac{1}{4}\left[ (L_x+i L_y)(L_x-iL_y) \right]
=\frac{1}{4} \left( L_x^2+L_y^2+i[L_y,L_x] \right)
=\frac{1}{4} \left( L_x^2+L_y^2+L_z \right)
$$
so you have finally

$$
H=\left[\frac{L^2}{8 I}-\frac{L_z}{8I}-\frac{L_z^2}{8I} \right]+\frac{L_z^2}{2I_z^2}
$$
using
$$
| 1,m \rangle
$$
you find immediately eigenvalues

N.B I used $ \hbar=1$

ALTERNATIVE:
Remember that
$$
L_{-} |1,m \rangle =\sqrt{2-m(m-1)} |1,m-1 \rangle, \quad L_{+}=\sqrt{2-m(m+1)} |1,m+1 \rangle
$$
so
$$
L_{+}L_{-} |1,m \rangle=\sqrt{2-m(m-1)}\sqrt{2-m(m-1)} |1,m \rangle
$$

Comment: I think they want us to use directly ladder operators

Comment: sorry for Latex

Comment: ok this seems fine, thx